# Can my webpage pick up the audio being played in the browser’s other tabs?

Tags: html, google-chrome, visualization, html5-audio

I am creating a HTML5 visualizer for a splash page. In my original briefing I was asked to make the page pick up whatever audio was coming out of the pc's speakers. My first question is, is this possible? I am assuming it that it is not as the ability to pick up microphone input seems to have only just been implemented.

My second option was to get the page to pick up whatever audio the browser was kicking out (on other tabs). Does anyone know how this might be done on, lets say, chrome?

I hope this is a good question. I am very new to website development.

Comment: That would arguably be a security vulnerability, if it were possible.

Comment: Sounds like a good question to me. Welcome to Stack Overflow. (Regarding your question: I have no idea, but I suspect not.)

Comment: There might be some sort of way if you implement it as a chrome app/plugin because they have more access to the browser than a regular website but as @lanzz said it's probably not possible because of security/privacy.